# Commit a python list into a single MYSQL column

Tags: mysql, database, list, python-3.7

I'm trying to store store several forms of data to a MYSQL database.
It's important that the data saves a list to a column entry. The data should look like this in the database:

```
ID----------var1----------list1-------------list2

1------------x-----------[1, 2, ..]---------[1, 2, ..]

2------------y-----------[2, 1, ..]---------[2, 1, ..]
```

Heres my current code:

```
mycursor.executemany(
                            "INSERT INTO fabric (consnames, consareaweight, consdensities, fccalc) VALUES (%i, %i, %i, %i)",
                            [(n, a, d, f) for n, a, d, f in
                             zip(cons_name, cons_area_weight, cons_density, fc_calc_true)])

                        mydb.commit()
```

which gives the following error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement
```

Is this the correct method?

Comment: @Strawberry, how would you handle this data?

Comment: @Strawberry So store the list as one long string and convert it to a list once its called upon?

Would you know how to convert a list to a string and string to a list?

Comment: No. I would store the list in a separate with one row per list item

Comment: @Strawberry got you the issue I have is that the list could be 1 item long ore 10 items long depending on user inputs. 

I'd imagine this may cause a lot of headaches..

Comment: @Strawberry So in my case I'd need two additional databases.

I'd need 4 columns to represent the four lists of data and then I'd need to multiply that by whatever my maximum list size would be (at the moment I'll assume 10)

Then I'd need to pull all the data and write code to check for blanks for when I pull the data back into python. I'd then have to organise the data into list for my program to use.

Comment: You might need additional tables, but one database should suffice. I don't know enough about what one list represents compared with another list, to say whether or not these should be separate tables.

Comment: @Strawberry yeah sorry seeperate tables same database. Just for ease of indexing in future! You're probably right though, more set-up now would mean everything runs smoother in future. I'll take that as my solution! Thanks!